# Fast, Scalable and Efficient Web development framework for beginners

Tags: javascript, java, python, node.js, ruby

I have knowledge of Core Java and I'm learning Python too.

What is the best web development framework for beginners?. I'm trying to develop a web portal for displaying some analytics and wanted to connect to docker, jenkins etc.

A good web development framework which is scalable, easy to learn and understand and which can help me in faster development.(Both for front end as well as back end)

I'm open to learn - so programming language and the software stack should not matter.

I have read many questions in and around this topic but have not found any constructive feedback on the subject. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something basic in Java, use [Servlets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/index.htm). Java servlets allow you to use java to make web pages at a very basic level. This is good if you aren't super experienced in making beautiful front-end pages.

Servlets are like embedding HTML in your java. It is almost like you are writing a Java program to print out a dynamically created webpage. i.e. (this is not even the right syntax, but just a peek at what your code will look like):

```
out.println("<HTML>");
out.println("<HEAD> <TITLE> My Webpage </TITLE> </HEAD>");
out.println("<BODY>");
out.println("<H1> Hello World! </H1>");
out.println("<UL>");
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    out.println("<LI>"+i+"</LI>);
}");
out.println("</UL>");
out.println("</BODY>");
out.println("</HTML>");
```

You can also use JSP, which is very outdated, looks like PHP, but does its job. JSP compiles to a Servlet internally, and looks like embedding java in your HTML: i.e. the same code as above:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD> <TITLE> My Webpage </TITLE> </HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1> Hello World! </H1>
<UL>
<% for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { %>
    <LI><%= i %></LI>
<% } %>
</UL>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

All the Java web frameworks like Struts, Stripes, Spring MVC... are built on servlets. I would suggest learning servlets before trying anything else.

If this answer helped you, please click the grey checkbox to the left to show StackExchange that this answer was useful.

Comment: Thanks vikarjramun.
I went ahead with MEAN stack which is beautiful. 
(Again, im looking at MERN stack as well as python-django too)